# How to serve static file over https in pm2?

Tags: node.js, ssl, pm2

we can serve our static files (like a frontend app) over http with a simple command in PM2 :

`pm2 serve <path> <port>`

How i can serve static files with SSL using the same command `pm2 serve`  ? is it possible ?

Or any alternatives using PM2 ?

Comment: You can't do that with pm2. But you can use nginx or apache.

Comment: Thats not possible: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/expose/

Answer (score 1):

A workaround to serve a static site with HTTPS using PM2 is to add [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) as a dependency to your project, then create a npm script to run serve, and have PM2 run that script instead of serving your site directly.

So, for example:

Add `serve` to your project:

```
npm -i serve
```

Add a script to your `package.json`, where 'build' is your build directory, and '8080' is the port you want to serve on:

```
  "scripts": {
    "serve-build": "serve -l 8080 -s build --ssl-cert 'path_to/your_certificate.crt' --ssl-key 'path_to/your_key.key'"
  },
```

Then instead of calling `pm2 serve <path> <port>`, you would instead tell PM2 to run npm and point at your script:

```
pm2 start npm --name your-pm2-process-name -- run serve-build
```

This will make PM2 run your script, which in turn runs `serve` which supports https when certificates are supplied. The process will then run in the same manner as if PM2 were serving the static site itself.