# Hosting a Create-React-App SPA on node.js with pm2 over HTTPS

Tags: node.js, https, create-react-app, pm2

I have successfully built and served a single page application built using create-react-app on node.js and pm2 over HTTP using the command:

`pm2 serve ~/my_site1/build 5001 --spa --name "my_site1.com"`

and then starting a proxy server to allow this, along with my other domains to be hosted simultaneously on port 80:

```
var httpProxy = require("http-proxy");

var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();
var options = {
  "my_site1.com": "http://555.555.555.555:5001",
  "my_site2.com": "http://555.555.555.555:5002",
};

http
  .createServer(function (req, res) {
    proxy.web(req, res, {
      target: options[req.headers.host],
    });
  })
  .listen(80);
```

This is all working perfectly, except, for various reasons, I now realise I need to be using HTTPS instead of HTTP, but I am stumped as to how to reconcile the various code fragments I see relating to this, e.g. this one that gets the certificates and creates a server directly:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const cert = fs.readFileSync('~/ssl/foo.crt');
const ca = fs.readFileSync('~/ssl/foo.ca-bundle');
const key = fs.readFileSync('~/ssl/foo.key');

let sslOptions = {
  cert: cert,
  ca: ca,
  key: key
};

const httpsServer = https.createServer(sslOptions, (req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.end("<h1>HTTPS server running</h1>");
});
```

I found via [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63047568/how-to-serve-static-file-over-https-in-pm2) that pm2 cannot directly run on HTTPS, and I don't want to have to abandon all the work I've put in so far to start again with a different approach as other articles suggest. I feel I'm very close and just need to adjust that final hop from port 5001 to HTTPS.

Is there a way to proxy my site (running on port 5001 via pm2) to port 443 and load in the certs at the same time? Or must the site itself be created on HTTPS (e.g. via https.CreateServer) in order to load the certs etc.?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I gave up and went to using **nginx** to reverse proxy to my existing pm2 running server on port :5001. This also included redirecting client http requests over to https.

There is a LOT of questions and answers on this issue, but after many false starts found the answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/145383/proxy-https-requests-to-a-http-backend-with-nginx).

After installing nginx, I edited the /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file to this (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the same IP throughout, "my_site" is the name of my domain name):

```
server {
        listen xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80;
        server_name my_site.com;

        rewrite ^(.*) https://$server_name$1 permanent;
}

server {
        listen xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443;
        server_name my_site.com;

        root /vhosts/my_site.com;

        ssl                     on;
        ssl_certificate        ssl/my_site/my_site_com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key    ssl/my_site/my_site_com.key;

        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_session_timeout 1d;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;

        # Diffie-Hellman parameter for DHE ciphersuites, recommended 2048 bits
        #ssl_dhparam /etc/pki/nginx/dh2048.pem;

        # intermediate configuration. tweak to your needs.
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE$

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5001;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        }
}
```